# Focus all input fields - Jquery

Tags: focus

How to focus all the four input text fields... Need to focus all the fields when there is an error $("#sar1").focus(); $("#sar2").focus(); $("#sar3").focus();

Its focussing only the last element. same is the case with below one too. $("#searchSeId").find("input[type=text]").each(function(){ $(this).focus(); });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't focus more than one input at a time.  Doing so would imply that you could edit the text in all focused fields simultaneously.  If that is really what you want, you would have to edit the other fields using a script onkeyup or onchange.

Instead, I would recommend adding a class using JavaScript:

```
$("#showerrors").click(function(){
  $("input[type=text]").each(function(){
    if ($(this).val() == "") {
      $(this).addClass("error");
    }
    else {
      $(this).removeClass("error");
    }
  });
})
```

And then apply a CSS red border, or something to indicate the fields with errors:

```
input.error {border:1px solid red;}
```

A very simple example of this can be found here, placing an error class on empty fields: http://jsfiddle.net/b3tnh6c0/